# how can we insert symbol of copyright in application programatically?

Tags: android

how can we insert symbol of copyright in application programatically?? if possible then please provide me example

Comment: Use &#169; instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is plain old Java, so it should work on Android. The "\u00a9" is Unicode for the copyright symbol.

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

class foo
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String unicodeMessage =
            "Copyright \u00a9 My Name";

        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
        out.println(unicodeMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the ampersand code for the copyright symbol:

```
   Copyright &copy; 2011, Stack Overflow
```